# Generate UML model by entering values in database using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, model, uml

I need to generate a UML activity model say for example a login page by storing all the data in database. I want to store the x and y axis of the shapes and their successor and predecessor. i tried in many ways bt couldnt get a satisfactory solution. Can any one provide me useful links or tools with which i can start building the App.

Comment: But the problem is to save data into db or drawing diagram itself?

Comment: I am able to draw diagrams using system.drawing.imaging. Problem is am not getting an idea of how to save it in database and make it work.

Comment: You can save image (as binary array or path), coordinates, size, arrows (arrow from one image to another), arrow start, arrow end, arrow style. I think is pretty complicated task.

Comment: can you share any related links so that i can get the steps to start

Comment: or is there any other approach for this?